# Programmatically Access custom user field

Tags: 7, entities, users

I added a Node-reference field (machine name: field_node) to all users at:

```
example.com/admin/config/people/accounts/fields/
```

I am now working in a custom module & `hook_node_access`

How do I access the Node-reference field programmatically when the user is logged in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get field values from any entity with [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7); the logged in user is available in the global `$user` object, and to load fields onto that object you can use [`user_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7).

Put those together and you get something like this:

```
// Get a fully loaded entity object for the logged in user.
$account = user_load($GLOBALS['user']->uid);

// Extract the field items
$field_items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_node');
if ($field_items) {
  // This will be 'target_id' if you're using the Entity Reference module, 
  // or 'nid' if you're using References
  $column_name = '?'; 

  $nid = $field_items[0][$column_name];
}
```

That's the abstract code if you like.

It's worth bearing in mind that `hook_node_access()` is passed an `$account` object already (which will be the logged in user if the access check is happening for them) so you would probably be better off using that to check against. You might still need to run it through `user_load()`, it'll be easy enough to check that with a bit of debugging.

Answer (score 7):

Two options here, using core API or entity_metadata_wrapper

```
global $user;
// Load full user account object
$account = user_load($user->uid);
// Get field;
$items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_node');
// Debug info
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($items,1).'</pre>');
// This gets the sanitized output, from the first field delta value (0)
$output = field_view_value('user', $account, 'field_node', $items[0]);
```

Relevant functions:

- [field_get_items](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7)
- [field_view_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7)

You can also, if using the Entity API module, use entity_metadata_wrapper

```
global $user;
$user_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($user_wrapper->field_node->raw(),1).'</pre>'); // Raw value
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($user_wrapper->field_node->value(),1).'</pre>'); // Loaded value
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, answer was posted while I was posting this answer.